# Access template's parent subscriptions state

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I know from the [Meteor doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) I can assess a template's subscriptions state by writing

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
  <!-- subscriptions ready -->
{{else}}
  <!-- loading -->
{{/if}}
```

What if want to access the template's parent state ?
I would like to write something like

```
{{#if Template.parent.subscriptionsReady}}
  <!-- parent's subscriptions ready -->
{{else}}
  <!-- loading -->
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [meteor-template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) package.

I created a helper:

```
Template.myTpl.helpers({
  parentSubscriptionsReady: function () {
    return Template.instance().parent(1).subscriptionsReady();
  }
});
```

and I use it like so:

```js
{{#if parentSubscriptionsReady}}
  <!-- parent's subscriptions ready -->
{{else}}
  <!-- loading -->
{{/if}}
```

Of course the helper can be defined as a global one using `Template.registerHelper`